# Advice needed on for loops Javascript loops and algorithms

Tags: javascript, loops

I need help with abstract for loop problems. 
This problem had to do with coming up with a way to have one result using a for loop. So for instance, I could change 20 and it would give me a different result each time. If I change number 20 to 4 the result should be 40320. I am having trouble wrapping my head around the logic to understanding this easier. Is there another way to write the variables to make it more simple? As an beginner I need advice on for loops.

```
 var number = 20;
 var i, prevResult, newResult;
 prevResult = 1;

   for (i = 1; i <= number - 1; i++) {
     // Calculate current result
         newResult = prevResult * (i + 1);

 // Set up the new result as the previous result
 prevResult = newResult;
}
console.log("FINAL RESULT: " + prevResult);
```

Thank you for reading and I hope to hear from you!

Comment: This would not fare well on Code Review as presented, as it sounds like they are looking for an explanation of code, rather than a review of code that is understood and works as intended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to add a specific question to your post. It is currently not clear what kind of response you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe not helpful but I just learned through experience. When you've written a hundred loops you'll know the pros and cons! `for (difficulty=d=9001; d > 0.0001; d = d - d * 0.2){ console.log(d) }`

Comment: So how is stackoverflow different than codereview? Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: See this for a comparison: [a guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I just edited my post! Hope this makes things easier. Thank you for you feedback!

Comment: Why should the result be 40320 when you are trying to calculate `4!`? The result of that factorial is and should be `24`. What don't you understand, the loop does it is supposed to do, although a little more code than actually needed (as commented by Lorenz Meyer in his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

- first you do not need prevResult and newResult. One variable is enough.
- it is an inconsistency to subtract 1 in `number - 1`,  and add it later in the body of the loop.
- `i = i + 1` can be written as `i++`, the increment operator
- `result = result * i` can be written as `result *= i`
- since `i` is only used inside the loop, declare it inside the loop.

This simplifies your code to :

```
var number = 20, result = 1; 
for (var i = 2; i <= number; i++)
{ // Calculate current result
    result *= i;
}
console.log("FINAL RESULT: " + result);
```

Comment: Wow this made it so much easier! Thank you so much!!

Comment: One question, when I run it on repl.it it states its an infinite loop. I want to calculate the factorial of the variable number. So If I were to change the number 20 to 4 it should give me one answer. if that makes sense? Here is the link, if you run it you can see it will only give you one answer for the factorial for loop. Hopefully I'm not confusing you even more https://repl.it/BY2b/2 Thank you again!

Comment: @SarahAbogabir, There is flaw in the OPs code, the `i = i++` should read only `i++` like in your original code. That causes the infinite loop

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still a little unclear, but you mention you have problems with 'abstract for loops'. Well, this for loop is not abstract, but rather concrete. Your indentation how ever is a little off, so let us start with proper indentation of your code:

```
var number = 20;
var i, prevResult, newResult;
prevResult = 1; 

for (i = 1; i <= number - 1; i++) {
    newResult = prevResult * (i + 1);
    prevResult = newResult;
}
console.log("FINAL RESULT: " + prevResult);
```

What happens here is that you first declare some variables for later use, amongst them the `number = 20` which later on will be the number of loops you repeat your for loop. The actual for loop consists of three parts:

- Initialisation: `i = 1` – Use `i` as a loop counter, and start on 1
- End condition: `i <= number - 1` – As long as `i` is less than or equal to `number - 1 = 20 -1 = 19`, keep on repeating the loop. Note that this could easier be written as `i < number`
- End of loop statement: `i++` – At the end of each loop, increment `i` with one

The code in your loop does the following:

- First time, with `i = 1`

  - Set `newResult` equal to `prevResult * (i + 1) = 1 * (1+1) = 2`
  - Set `prevResult` to this newly calculated value, i.e. `2`
- Second time, now `i` has incremented due to the end of loop statement, so `i = 2`:

  - Set `newResult` equal to `prevResult * (i + 1) = 2 * (2+1) = 6`
  - Set `prevResult` to the newly calculated value, i.e. `6`
- And so it continues:

  - `i = 3` gives `newResult =  6 * (3+1) = 24`
  - `i = 4` gives `newResult = 24 * (4+1) = 120`
  - ...
- When `i = 19`, the loop does the following:

  - Set `newResult` equal to `prevResult * (i + 1) = 121645100408832000 * (19 + 1) = 2432902008176640000`
  - And sets `prevResult = 2432902008176640000`
- Now the end of loop statement, kicks in and increments `i` once more, and `i = 20`, but now it checks this against the end condition, and 20 is not less than or equal to 10, so it stops executing the loop, and your code print out the correct number for `20!`

So your code is actually working, and changing `number = 20` to `number = 4` or similar will change it to calculating `4!` instead of `20!`. So the question remains, what is unclear and abstract for you regarding this execution?